# Make `node --prof` wait a bit before recording anything?

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling

I have a script that is mostly callbacks for network events. The callbacks finish very quickly. In contrast, the script takes a relatively long time to initialize. I don't really care how long it takes to initialize, I just want to optimize the event callbacks. If I run `node --prof`, most of the results are from the initialization.

How can I make Node not record anything until it's done initializing? In other words, how can I programmatically enable and disable profiling?

Answer (score 2):

You could always pipe the output into [flamebearer](https://github.com/mapbox/flamebearer) to get a flame graph.

```
node --prof app.js
node --prof-process --preprocess -j isolate*.log | npx flamebearer
```

It won't stop node from profiling your entire application, but it will likely give you enough information to drill down in the flame graph and ignore the pieces around the edges that you don't want to see, like the app bootstrap.

---

You could always try executing the code that you want to profile in a loop as well, to give them a larger representation. Or use `node --prof` in tandem with `benchmark`.

Comment: Looping is an interesting idea, I'll try it. I tried flame graphs but they don't go into enough detail. I.e. there's a limit to how far I can zoom into a call stack. Maybe I'm just using it wrong

Comment: Hm. Could be that the event loop stuff ends up in its own call stack, perhaps. I don't suppose you could trim the code down in a way where you can execute _just_ the callback methods? Whenever I need to optimize something like that, I always try to run the methods as isolated as I can. It'll make it much easier to profile (and easier to test too, as a nice side effect).

Answer (score 0):

`node --prof` is meant to profile the entire application from the beginning. You could try using another profiler like vTune or the one built into webstorm. Another thing I would try is [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug). Debug can be used to log the time it takes between events, which I think is what you are trying to go for.